# How to list 3 largest numbers from table in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm trying to unite two bits of SQL codes and list three largest numbers from it. [Here is table relation diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VshmC.png)

Query #1:

```
SELECT MAX(d) AS deliveries
FROM (SELECT o.rider_id, COUNT(o.rider_id) d
FROM orders o
GROUP BY o.rider_id) AS alias;
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM users;
```

My final code shows the full list of all first and second names, simply adding largest number to all of them from `orders` table. How can I modify it to make it show three names with its largest delivery count?

```
SELECT u.first_name, u.last_name, MAX(d) AS deliveries
FROM (SELECT o.rider_id, COUNT(o.rider_id) d
FROM orders o
GROUP BY o.rider_id) AS alias
JOIN users u
GROUP BY u.first_name, u.last_name;
```

Comment: Please *tag* your specific database. AS written your query should give a syntax error your join has no ON criteria.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server? T-SQL? MySQL? What SQL?

Comment: MariaDB doesn't give me any error messages connected to ON criteria.

Comment: On all SQL based questions please start by showing all the relevant table schemas, some example table data is also useful. If you can build a SQLFiddle with the relevant tables and some test data thats even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want exactly the top 3 (or less if there are less than 3) then use order by the attribute you want, and use limit:

```
SELECT u.first_name, u.last_name, MAX(d) AS deliveries
FROM (SELECT o.rider_id, COUNT(o.rider_id) d
FROM orders o
GROUP BY o.rider_id) AS alias
JOIN users u
GROUP BY u.first_name, u.last_name
ORDER BY deliveries DESC
LIMIT 3;
```